# Extracting Word count / frequency count using Wordnet database

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, wordnet

I am looking for word count/frequency extraction according to the word's usage in general English like http://www.wordcount.org/main.php. I am using JWNL api for accessing Wordnet dictionary and I am unable to find any way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into the Google N-Grams corpus. The unigram counts will give you the relative frequencies of each word. At one point, I actually did go through this and link all of the words in WordNet to their corresponding n-gram count; you can find my list here:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gangeli/sim/master/etc/weighted_wordnet_vocabulary.tab

Note that this is in no way a "canonical" list that's in any way officially supported, it's just something I put together once.